# Android JNI String Problem

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

JAVA_CODE:

```
 public class Employee {
        private int age;
        private String name;

        public Employee(int age, String name) {
            this.age  = age;
            this.setName(name);
        }
        public int getAge() {
            return this.age;
        }
        public void setAge(int age) {
                this.age = age;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name; 
        }
    }
```

C Structure:

```
typedef struct Employee_s {
   int age;
   char name[200];
}Employee_t;
```

JNI Code Look:

```
jint
Java_com_example_cloudonlibtest_CloudOnLibTestActivity_second( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject this, jobject employeeObject)
{
    Employee_t em;
    em.age =418;
    strcpy(em.name, "TheCat");
    jclass employeeClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, employeeObject);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,employeeClass , "setAge", "(I)V");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env,employeeObject, mid,em.age);
    jmethodID st = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,employeeClass , "setName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env,employeeObject, st, em.name);
    return 1;
}
```

I am able to set the age field, but failed to set the name failed. What wrong with my code?

---

```
It didn't work see log below
I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 330, tid: 330  >>> com.example.jni <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 00000374  r1 0000000c  r2 0000000c  r3 deadd00d
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000026  r5 80887fc4  r6 00000000  r7 fffe6624
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 bed4e8e8  r9 4186bccc  10 4186bcb4  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip 808881ec  sp bed4e808  lr afd154c5  pc 8083b162  cpsr 20000030
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 0003b162  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 0002cff4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 0002d11a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #03  pc 0002dbf0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #04  pc 00000542  /data/data/com.example.jni/lib/libtest-lib.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #05  pc 00013974  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #06  pc 0003de3c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #07  pc 00037216  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #08  pc 000432ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #09  pc 00018714  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #10  pc 0001e8c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #11  pc 0001d790  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #12  pc 0005408e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #13  pc 0005bde2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #14  pc 00018714  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #15  pc 0001e8c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #16  pc 0001d790  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #17  pc 00053eec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #18  pc 0004072c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #19  pc 00034454  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #20  pc 0002c930  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #21  pc 0002d85c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #22  pc 00008c86  /system/bin/app_process
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #23  pc 0000d362  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31): 
I/DEBUG   (   31): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   31): 8083b140 1861447c 200618a2 e878f7d8 f7d82000 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 8083b150 4808e9e4 6bdb5823 d0002b00 4b064798 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 8083b160 701c2426 ea5cf7d8 0004ce80 fffe4ae0 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 8083b170 fffe801c 00000374 deadd00d b510b40e 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 8083b180 4c0a4b09 447bb083 aa05591b 6b5bca02 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 
I/DEBUG   (   31): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   31): afd154a4 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
I/DEBUG   (   31): afd154b4 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
I/DEBUG   (   31): afd154c4 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
I/DEBUG   (   31): afd154d4 bdf01c30 0002ae7c 000000d4 1c0fb5f0 
I/DEBUG   (   31): afd154e4 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 
I/DEBUG   (   31): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7c8  00000015  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7cc  afd1453b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7d0  afd405a0  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7d4  afd4054c  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7d8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7dc  afd154c5  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7e0  0000ccb0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7e4  afd1450d  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7e8  fffe6624  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7ec  80887fc4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7f0  80887fc4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7f4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7f8  fffe6624  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e7fc  afd1456b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e800  df002777  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e804  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (   31): #00 bed4e808  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e80c  8082cff9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   31): #01 bed4e810  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     bed4e814  8082d11f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/BootReceiver(   59): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
```

Comment: You did not mention why you must use JNI for this. But if performance is important, you should consider setting the fields directly and avoid switching back and forth between native mode and java mode by calling `CallVoidMethod`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create and pass a Java `String` object `(Ljava/lang/String;)`, not a native string.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#4035

Comment: If i transfer the string as an input paramter to the function, there is no problem,
But the string is a private paramter of a class, so how can i access it and update it with a value

Answer (score 4):

Any time you see a fault address of 0xdeaddood, you know that the VM aborted deliberately (calling dvmAbort):

I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d

so if you look above that in the log, you should see it printed a *reason* why it aborted.

If you're writing JNI, you should also be using CheckJNI: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is working method on C. Try this, if you have questions please ask ...

```
jclass employeeClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, employeeObject);
jfieldID fid = NULL;
char* ped = "TheCat";
fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, employeeClass, "setName", "Ljava/lang/String;");
if( fid != NULL ) {
    jstring myStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF( env, ped);
    // Set "eventData".
    (*env)->SetObjectField(env, enrollClassObject, fid, myStr);
}
```